# Drop Down list in a UIViewController

Tags: ios7

I have a question to all of you. Is there any concept of drop down list in iOS?Means if i click the arrow then a drop down list will come out.I know the concept of date picker and picker view. Is there any other solutions..?

Comment: https://cocoapods.org/pods/iOSDropDown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not any drop down list Concept in iOS , You can use Some Custom Library for that.

You can find some Library at Cocoacontrols.com

Check this [NIDropDown](https://github.com/BijeshNair/NIDropDown) ,[SAMenuDropDown](https://github.com/satishazad/SAMenuDropDown).

or Create your own with **UITableview** ,

Try this out.

```
1) Add the UITableView on a transparent UIView. 
2) The UIView should have the same size as the display screen.
3) The UITableView shall take the same small size you have.
4) Implement the touches method as you mentioned for the holding UIView.
```

Comment: @Rupayan_90: check https://github.com/BijeshNair/NIDropDown/archive/master.zip download project , use

Comment: Thanks a lot..Its such a nice example